clangd disable inlay hints for BlockEnd is not working
My project level settings.json is like following:
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "disabled",
    "C_Cpp.formatting": "clangFormat",
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "file",
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "Microsoft",
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_path": "<path to `clang-format` binary>",
    "clangd.path": "<path to `clangd` binary>",
    "clangd.arguments": [
        "-log=verbose", 
        "-pretty", 
        "--background-index", 
        "--background-index-priority=low",
        "--clang-tidy",
        "--enable-config",
    ],

In the .clangd file at project level, I have added followings:
InlayHints:
  Enabled: Yes
  BlockEnd: No
  Designators: No
  ParameterNames: Yes
  DeducedTypes: Yes
  TypeNameLimit: 0


However, I am still getting inlay hints at block end for C++ files. What am I missing?
I am using VS Code from windows with remote connection. I have clangd extension installed and clangd version in remote machine is 19.1.0

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your setup. I would encourage you to file an issue at https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues with added details (e.g. example code, clangd logs) for further diagnosis.

Sure - I'll file one.

@HighCommander4 - resolved through suggestion in the github issue (https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/2250).

Resolved the issue as per suggestions in the github issue. User config takes precedence over the project config. When I was setting up VS Code initially, a user config got created. I had to delete the user config to resolve it (could have removed the project config as well).
On Linux, the user config was under ${HOME}/.config/clangd/config.yaml
